# How to enable TCP on MAMP?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I'm trying to run cake in the command line and I'm getting this error

PDO::__construct(): [2002] Connection refused (trying to connect via tcp://127.0.0.1:3306)

I did some research and it turns out that TCP is not turned on automatically with MAMP.

I looked around to see if I could locate a mysql conf file but I could not.

I am using Mamp 2.1.1 on OSX 10.8.2

Does anyone know what I need to do to enable TCP on MAMP, and how to do it? (I am not using MAMP PRO)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just use the socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to connect over TCP, you need to [enable networking](http://www.razorsql.com/docs/support_mysql_mac_mamp.html) in your mysql config file, by removing the skip-networking line.

Instead of enabling networking, if you're only going to talk to mysql on the local machine you can connect over a local socket. In place of the tcp connection, give PDO the socket name, like `mysql:unix_socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` This will work without any changes to MAMP's defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm new to this, how would I go about giving PDO the socket name

Comment: When you create the PDO object, you can specify what you want to connect to. See: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php  When connecting via socket, pass it a string like in my answer above.